# What is the URL helper path for header logo in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to remove the home page link from the header logo when a user is on the checkout page in magento but I cant find where the path of this is so i can remove in my local.xml file with code similar to below.

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
  <reference name="header"> 
     <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
         <url helper="PATH TO MAIN LOGO URL" />
     </action> 
  </reference>  
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

tadhg,You cannot do this by xml code.
you need to go `app/design/frontent/your Package/your Template/template/page/html/header.phtml`

Here you need condition which is skip logo only for checkout onepage.

```
<?php
$currentRoute=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName().'_'.Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName().'_'.Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
if($currentRoute!='checkout_onepage_index'): ?>

 <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">....
 ....
 <a>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. but I would like to keep the logo there, just remove the link behind it. I can do it for every page in the admin tool, but I dont know how to restrict this link removal just for the checkout onepage.

Answer (score 0):

just unset the header from checkout page and add new header.

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/header.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Hope this will help !!!!!!

Comment: thanks Manoj but unsetChildren removes everything except the header logo!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to just remove the link from one page so on the checkout page i'm replacing my header using

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
     <reference name="root">
         <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header" template="page/html/header2.phtml"/>
     </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

and in my local themes template creating 'header2.phtml' in page/html with a header file with a logo but removing the link (deleting `href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>"` from the 'logo' class.)